# Magento2 : How To Access Custom Parameter's of Admin Url in admin login page

Tags: magento2, admin, login, parameter, get

this is my admin url : http://127.0.0.1/m2-test/index.php/admin?username=test

and i want to access **username** value in admin login.phtml

i have tried with **$_GET["username"]** but it will return nothing

Does  anyone have idea about this issue ?.